# Migration Update Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How do I update my schema within the php artisan migrate. I already have the tables created, but I want to be able to update a column to cascade on delete.

I have the schema updated, but it keeps saying nothing to migrate. When I use `migrate:refresh` I get an error saying a table is not found.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('invoices', function($table)
    {
          $table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customers')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

and

```
php artisan migrate
```

another one. If you'll get some errors try

```
composer dumpautoload
```

I had same issue and it helps